Should physicalists define "physical," or should non-physicalists define "non-physical"?
When discussing the fundamental nature of reality, physicalists often argue that, as far as we can tell, everything that exists is physical. They contend that anyone claiming the existence of something beyond the physical bears the burden of proof: they must explain what "non-physical" even means, demonstrate that the concept is coherent, and provide compelling evidence for the existence of non-physical entities.
Critics of physicalism, however, often challenge it by arguing the notion of "physical" is itself vague and poorly defined (e.g., see The coherence of physicalism: are there any solutions to Hempel's dilemma?).
This raises an important question about the burden of proof:

Does it rest on the physicalist, who must show that the concept of "physical" is coherent and that everything can be explained as physical?
Or does it fall on the non-physicalist, who must demonstrate that the idea of the "non-physical" is coherent and provide compelling evidence for the existence of at least one non-physical thing?


Addressing duplicate charges
This question is NOT a duplicate of Burden of proof. That question asks:

Who has the burden of proof when trying to prove or disprove someone's religious beliefs? I have always believed it belongs to the person who is making a claim but can there be exceptions?

My question is not about religious beliefs. Religion is orthogonal to my question. A physicalist can be religious. A non-physicalist can be non-religious.

Traditionally the demarcation was clear on both sides since non-physical usually refers to that which is ideal. Contemporary demarcation you can simply define non-physical as those emerging supervening or unexplainable by physics in theory alone. Like many chemistry cannot be explained by physics via practical computations but many believe can be reduced to physics in theory…

There is never any burden of proof for anyone unless they're in a criminal procedure or  want to convince someone else who has a different opinion to adopt their opinion. Voting to close since this is duplicate of several other questions about "burden of proof".

As a non-physicalist, I've defined "the physical" to be "reasons why I am right and physicalists are wrong". Since physicalists believe that all is physical, I win. Hurray!

These endless questions are proving to be a burden.

I agree with Lowri's answer that each person should define the terms they use, and strive to communicate clearly and have productive discussions.
Physicalist and non-physicalist are useful labels. But getting hung up on definitions of such abstract metaphysical distinctions (and who should have what burden based on those distinctions) could be counter-productive and may not lead anywhere useful.
What seems more important is:

What methods are "good" for arriving at beliefs (e.g. is it reliable - how often does it produce true or seemingly-true beliefs)?
What are the claims in question, and which of those are true, or which are we justified in accepting?

Each person should be able to explain this own methods for arriving at beliefs. This isn't really a "burden of proof" issue. It's just helpful for having discussions and trying to come to agreement about what's true.
Physicalism is heavily tied to empirical and scientific investigation, and doesn't posit anything beyond that (whether "physical" or "non-physical", whether a specific distant imperceptible planet or a god, we don't seem to have good reason to accept the existence of such things, for the time being).
Non-physicalism (except for idealism, mostly) tends to accept the existence of the same things that physicalism does, but:

It posits that some of those things (consciousness, in particular) are non-physical (or similar), or
It posits the existence of additional non-physical or supernatural things

For positing the existence of additional things, the burden of proof would clearly be on that, to justify the claim and provide a reason to think that exists.
For positing that something is non-physical, it would be on them to explain what that means, where and how it exists, and how that connects to the observable world. And we can compare that to an explanation purely based in the observable world (e.g. consciousness reduces to brain activity), to decide which explanation is better based on e.g. explanatory power.

Every communicator has a burden to be clear about what they're saying. It is for the person making an argument to make clear for their audience what they mean.
If a "non-physicalist" encounters someone whose barrier to accepting their argument, or even to participating in fruitful discussion, is the vagueness of the "non-physical," and if the non-physicalist desires to engage that critic further, it is probably prudent to explain more what they mean by the "non-physical."
The same goes for a "physicalist" seeking to communicate with someone who finds their notion of "physical" to be vague.
If both strive to be clear, there may be some meaningful discussion.
This is not about burden of proof; it is about practical communication.

I broadly agree. Although it often feels like some non-physicalists don't have much interest in communicating clearly and having fruitful discussion, when physicalists say they don't define multiple categories of existing things but non-physicalists keep asking them to differentiate between 2 categories.


Should physicalists define "physical," or should non-physicalists define "non-physical"?

This ultimately depends on the nature of the discussion/debate. In  a philosophical/verbal debate physicalists' definition is no better than any other... however, if we debate about constructing an airplane, there are good reasons to trust a physicalist. Finally, if it comes to blows, physicalists' could win by physically destroying their opponents, but not the other way round - baseball bat is sometimes the strongest argument.
The above is not intended as an argument in favor of physicalism - rather I am trying to point out that the Q. makes assumptions about framing of the debate, which do not necessarily hold.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@Geoffrey Thomas Of course it's okay to push the thread into the chat. But you have a serious background in philosophy yourself, don't you want to follow along and help clarify the point?

@tenebris: Thank you for your remarks about my background in philosophy. I don't make a decision or a judgement-call about moving comments to Chat. The site rule, which I follow along with other Moderators, is to transfer comments to Chat once a limit of 20 has been reached. I see how this can cut an interesting and valuable thread, but discussion can always be continued in Chat. Best - Geoffrey
